# How to do "INSERT INTO table1 (...) SELECT (...) FROM table2" in LINQ?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

How do I write a LINQ to SQL equivalent of:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (field1, field2, field3)
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM Table2
WHERE (field1= @field1)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Since you aren't returning any results, just use the low-level `DataContext.ExecuteCommand()` method:

```
using (MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext())
{
    dc.ExecuteCommand(@"
        INSERT INTO Table1 (field1, field2, field3)
        SELECT field1, field2, field3
        FROM Table2
        WHERE (field1= {0})
        ",
        field1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

LINQ is a querying language, so it doesn't do updates or inserts. However -the LINQ to SQL entity object model has methods for handling CUD:

```
using(MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext())
{
    //select the source entities from Table2
    var Table2Entities = (from e in dc.Table2 where e.Field1 == "value" select e);

    //for each result, create a new Table1 entity and attach to Table1
    Table2Entities.ForEach(t2e => dc.Table1.InsertOnSubmit(
        new Table1Entity {
            Field1 = t2e.Field1,
            Field2 = t2e.Field2,
            Field3 = t2e.Field3
        });

    //submit the changes
    dc.SubmitChanges();
}
```

The real difference here is that it requires two separate SQL transactionsinstead of one - one to select, and one to insert.

Comment: Do you have any documentation to backup the assertion that all of the insertions take place in one round trip?

Comment: @Adam nope. Just my memory, which is often faulty. I'll remove that bit 'till it's cleared up one way or the other. Thanks!

Comment: @Adam, the SQL Profiler tool will shed some light on how LINQ-to-SQL is communicating with the database server and is a good way to measure performance and how well LINQ is constructing its queries and batches.

Comment: @David: Yes, that's true. I'm not at work right now so I don't have access to it, and my (possibly incorrect) assumption was that LINQ's data access layer dealt with SQL as ADO did, with one command per row.

Answer (score 0):

If field of both the tables is same then,
use

`insert into table1 select * from table2 where table2.field1='xyz';`

in place of:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (field1, field2, field3)
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM Table2
WHERE (field1= @field1)
```